# Create a folder and add properties (field values) to it on form submission

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, client-object-model, jsom, ootb

I have created a simple form on SP site, on the submission of which a folder with entered name in the form would get created in the desired doc library.Library has some custom columns such as Description,Start Date, End Date.Now I want to enhance the code such that the custom column values pertaining to this folder should get inserted at the time of creation.

```
<form>
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD>Project Name</TD>
<TD>
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="project_name" NAME="name" SIZE="30">
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Description</TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="Description" NAME="email" SIZE="30"></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

</form>

<div><button onclick=" retrieveWebSite()">Create</button></div>  

<div id="displayDiv"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">   
function retrieveWebSite() {
var clientContext;
var oWebsite;
var oList;
var itemCreateInfo;
var folderName =  document.getElementById('project_name').value;
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Project");

itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
itemCreateInfo.set_leafName(folderName);
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
this.oListItem.update();

clientContext.load(this.oListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
    Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
);

function successHandler() {
   alert('A new project folder has been created successfully.Please check Existing Project');
}

function errorHandler() {
  alert('Some Error occured');
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why create Forms yourself if SharePoint IS all about Forms and Views? Which you can enhance with script! Have you seen the SharePoint DocumentSets?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
function retrieveWebSite() {
    var clientContext;
    var oWebsite;
    var oList;
    var itemCreateInfo;
    var folderName =  document.getElementById('project_name').value;

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Project");
    clientContext.load(oList);

    var parentFolder = oList.get_rootFolder();
    clientContext.load(parentFolder);    

    //set the properties of the folder, use internal name of column
    var properties = {};
    properties['Desc'] = "test desc";
    var startDate = new Date();
    properties['StartDate'] = startDate.toISOString();

    itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
    itemCreateInfo.set_leafName(folderName);
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);

}

function successHandler() {
   console.log('A new project folder has been created successfully.Please check Existing Project');
   var createdFolder = oWebsite.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(parentFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '/' + folderName);
   var createdFolderItem = createdFolder.get_listItemAllFields();
        if (properties != null) {
            for (var property in properties) {
                if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property) === true) {
                    createdFolderItem.set_item(property, properties[property]);
                }
            }
        }
        createdFolderItem.update();
        clientContext.load(createdFolderItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            console.log("success updating properties");
        }, function(){
            console.log("failure updating properties");
        });

}

function errorHandler() {
  console.log('Some Error occured');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to submit additional form data is by adding additional input fields to the upload form:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="example1" value="test">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Example: <input type="text" name="example2"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

By default, the plugin calls jQuery's `serializeArray` method on the upload form to gather additional form data for all input fields (including hidden fields).
The value of these form fields will be sent to the server along with the selected files.

Note:
If you set the `formData` option, these fields won't be sent to the server, since the formData object will override them.
You can however create a `formData` object of the form fields manually using jQuery's `serializeArray` method method:

```
var formData = $('form').serializeArray();
```

Comment: To me this is directly plagiarized from  https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data and not necessarily suitable for SharePoint.

Comment: @moe is correct, this does not pertain to SharePoint.  This would be useful for submitting forms in a different environment, but not for SharePoint.